# Python launch exe file error

Tags: c#, python

I have written a .exe file in C# and it works fine if I launch it manually by hand (double clicking) but everytime I tried to open it with python.

```
import  os
os.system('"D:\\XX\MyFile.exe"')
```

I have also tried this :

```
import subprocess 

exefile = 'D:\\XX\\MyFile.exe'
subprocess.call([exefile])
```

The program crashes immediately saying "**MyFile.exe has stopped working. A program caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.**".

Now what puzzles me is that if I run it manually its working but when i try to launch it via Python it fails.

The C# application is simply a Updater that I wrote to check for updates for my pythonscripts. It has a .dll that contains the update routines and the forms that loads a (.dat) file for information.

Is there something that I miss?

**EDIT:**

Upon some modifications and diagnosis, my exefile now starts but I realize if it was launched by Python, the exe couldn't do the following function in my C# Application.

```
private UpdateSaveFile DecodeSaveFile(string LocalUpdateFile)
    {
        FileStream localFileStream = null;
        BinaryFormatter decoder = null;
        try
        {
            localFileStream = File.Open(LocalUpdateFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            decoder = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (UpdateSaveFile)decoder.Deserialize(localFileStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException("The local update info file is corrupt!", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (localFileStream != null)
                localFileStream.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Now whenever I run the exefile from python, it throws me the "The local update info file is corrupt". But if I run the exefile manually (without python) / cmd prompt , it works just perfectly fine.

Anyone has any idea ? Is it because of administrator rights? Does python launched exe have admin rights?

Comment: Any reason you are doing `exefile = '%s' % 'D:\\XX\\MyFile.exe'` instead of `exefile = 'D:\\XX\\MyFile.exe'` ?

Comment: Having four quote marks in the first code block seems strange to me. Have you tried `os.system("D:\\XX\MyFile.exe")` instead?

Comment: I think `os.system(r'D:\XX\MyFile.exe')` is better

Comment: Why not only `import subprocess subprocess.Popen([r"MyFile.exe"]` ? Can you try this one please

Comment: I tried all the above comments but it's the same :( do I have to specify anything for the exe ? Because my program has a .dll and it doesn't run that perhaps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the culprit. So I have a string like this: It should look at the current directory for the file "Updates.dat". However for some reasons, if I launch the exe via Python. It couldn't recognize the ".\" but if i manually run it , it's fine. This really puzzles me.

```
const String LocalUpdateFile = @".\Updates.dat";
```

So, instead if I change to this. The python launched exe works fine.

```
const String LocalUpdateFile = @"D:\XX\Updates.dat";
```

But I am really curious why this is happening.. If anyone has any solution, please let me know.

Thanks!