# Get Directory: Object Reference required for non-static field, method or property

Tags: c#

Hi I am having trouble get the directory name of the executable:

Originally I had this line, it works fine but then when I launch the exe via Python, it fails and I detailed my problem in this post here ([Python launch exe file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949217/python-launch-exe-file-error/28098726#28098726))

```
const String LocalUpdateFile = @".\Updates.dat";
```

So I change my code to this which solves my problem:

```
const String LocalUpdateFile = @"C:\XX\Updates.dat";
```

But i want the directory path to be dynamic so i use this but I am stuck:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

const String LocalUpdateFile = appPath+@"\UpdateInfo.dat";
```

It is telling me this error:

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'xx.appPath'  xx\Updater.cs   20  34  xx

Anybody care to explain what happened ? :(

Comment: Does appPath have a trailing "\"?  I tend to use Path.Combine() to avoid the issue completely.

Comment: You can't have a `const` that updates at run-time.  It can be `readonly` but not `const`.

Comment: I would also recommend debugging your code and evaluating `appPath` and `LocalUpdateFile` to see if you see anything out of the ordinary..also do you realize that consts can't be changed .. change it to public or static

Comment: @MethodMan this appears to be a compile time error, so there's nothing to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define a constant based on non-static field. Try this, change is in the second code line:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string LocalUpdateFile = appPath+@"\UpdateInfo.dat";
```

Or if you declare the fields outside of a method/property:

```
static string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
const string LocalUpdateFile = appPath+@"\UpdateInfo.dat";
```

Comment: Nope , still telling me the same error: 

Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'xx.Updater.appPath' xx\Updater.cs 18 28 xx

Comment: @Arbitel `appPath` needs to be `static` to use it in a field initializer.

Comment: it would truly help if the OP would show the full method signature so that we can see how he's trying to assign / declare appPath.. I suggested `static` declaration in my earlier post as well